# What is the difference between upgrading from the system and using a CD? My Apache got hosed from CD upgrade

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, 12.04, apache2

Question pretty much sums it up. I was running Ubuntu 11.10 and had Apache serving a few virtual hosts. I popped in the Ubuntu 12.04 CD (Beta 2) and rebooted. I choose to 'Upgrade Ubuntu 11.10'.

The result is that my home folder is still intact and most settings seem to be there, but I couldn't access any of my sites. I eventually realised that apache no longer exists on the system!

Anyway, if I had done this at work (and I *could* have), I would have made quite a mess for myself. I understand that it's not Ubuntus job to educate me and that as a techy I need to know these things. But I really thought it would be the same as upgrading from the Update Manager.

Can anyone explain?

Many Thanks,
Ten

Comment: Well, possibly the wording of the menu option is wrong - instead of "Upgrade Ubuntu 11.10" it should've been "Make a clean install over 11.10 keeping my home folder intact". I never tried this "upgrade from CD" option but somehow I always thought that's what it actually does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The livecd can not upgrade, only replace the existing install with a new one, so if you did that, you would no longer have any packages installed that aren't part of the base install.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that's what it looks like happened. I'll boot the CD again and check the wording. If it's as I remember, I'll file a bug report. I probably should have just put the CD in on the desktop and upgraded from there.

Answer (score 1):

12.04 is not final yet and since the release of Beta 2 over 3 weeks ago lots of packages got updated. I would not expect such a feature to work flawlessly in Beta state. Did you really upgrade from CD, not just reinstall?

In theory the installation media contains a repository of packages and the upgrade from installation media functionality works like the regular upgrade but prioritizes packages from the installation media. Obviously the CD only contains a very limited number of packages needed for the default install. The DVD contains a lot more packages, but not all. The upgrade should detect your selection of packages and replace them with newer ones. Packages not found locally should be downloaded if there is an Internet connection available. The upgrade should warn about PPAs, software that is going to be removed and replacement/alteration of configuration files if I recall correctly. In case of no Internet connection, the package should be removed/uninstalled but the configuration files shouldn't be altered.

That said upgrading from installation media and without installation media should be the same. As long as there are packages for your installed applications in the repository of the new release you're upgrading to nothing should be uninstalled. If you don't have an Internet connection at the time of upgrade and no local repository with the package for the new release, then of course no package can be found and the application will be uninstalled.